# Geocoding using leaflet not working

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I'm using a leaflet plugin to prform on the flr geocoding of address fields. When I used a callback function to get the results, the fuction doesn't execute. Below is a sample code,

```
var googleGeocodeProvider = new L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google(),
  addressText = 'Amsterdam';

googleGeocodeProvider.GetLocations( addressText, function (data) {
console.log(data)

});
```

Getlocations is not getting executed and I'm not getting anything in console.log. Are there any solutions and can anyone help on this?

Comment: Have you checked out the code for the demo from the plugin's GitHub page?  [Demo](http://smeijer.github.io/L.GeoSearch/)

Comment: yes. But I no need a search bar or  a tool. I need to geocode data and get the lat long and display the markers.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the [Demo from the plugin's developer](http://smeijer.github.io/L.GeoSearch/) you can add the code you have above.  It would look something like this:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="src/js/l.control.geosearch.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/l.geosearch.provider.google.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/l.geosearch.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var osmTileUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var basemap = new L.TileLayer(osmTileUrl, { maxZoom: 18 });

    var map = new L.Map('map', {
        layers: [basemap],
        center: new L.LatLng(53.2, 5.8), zoom: 12
    });

    var googleGeocodeProvider = new L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google(),
        addressText = 'Amsterdam';

    googleGeocodeProvider.GetLocations(addressText, function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        L.marker([data[0].Y, data[0].X]).addTo(map);
        map.setView([data[0].Y, data[0].X]);

    });

</script></body></html>
```

In the callback from the GetLocations I added a maker for the coordinates and then set the map view to them.  You would need to adjust for however you are getting your addresses of course.  Also in this case the search text 'Amsterdam' returns two results, I'm just grabbing the first here so you would need to build in logic to handle multiple returns. 
The result in the console is:

[image]

Don't forget to add your google maps api key to this file: l.geosearch.provider.google.js.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm executing the same as urs. Its not entering the call back function at all. Dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post your entire code so we can take a look?